# How to calculate the values of a column based on adjacent column vaules?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with true/false values. What I want to do is add a column with incrementing values based on t/f column (see example below). How can I do this using python?

| T/F value | Expected outcome |
| --- | --- |
| False | 0 |
| False | 1 |
| False | 2 |
| True | 0 |
| True | 1 |
| False | 0 |

Comment: what is the rule for your calculation? Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: I'd recommend posting your expected outcome.  Also add any code you have tried so far to show the direction you're heading in.

Comment: You seem to have removed the initial data.  Can you post "Given these two columns SHOW TABLE 1, I would like to have a third  column like this SHOW TABLE 2.  The logic is for the third column is..xyz123."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While mozway's answer is definitely shorter, it may not be the most beginner-friendly, and hard to read. Thus I am adding on a much easier to understand approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'False'])

def indexer(col):
    result = []
    trueCount = -1  # -1 since you want to start counting from 0
    falseCount = -1
    for i in col:
        if i == 'True':
            trueCount += 1
            falseCount = -1  # reset back to -1 since the T/F changed from last cell
        else:
            falseCount += 1
            trueCount = -1  # reset back to -1 since the T/F changed from last cell
        result.append(max(trueCount, falseCount))  # one of them will definitely be -1
    return result

df['count'] = indexer(df.iloc[:, 0].tolist())
```

The function takes a pandas column converted to a list as input, and iterate through every cell. It then checks for the value of each cell and modifies the counters accordingly. When the value of the current cell does not match with the previous, the counter of the unmatched value will be reset. Finally, we take the max of both counters since one of them must be reset to -1. The calculated value for each cell is then appended onto a list and returned.

Comment: This will be much slower on large datasets as it iterates over the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can huse `shift` to calculate when the T/F values are changing and `groupby`+`cumcount` to calculate the cumulated counts:

```
s = df['T/F value']
df['Calculation'] = df.groupby((s!=s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

output:

```
   T/F value  Calculation
0      False            0
1      False            1
2      False            2
3       True            0
4       True            1
5      False            0
```